# Galleriffic Multiple thumbnail galleries with single slideshow container

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery, image-gallery

I managed to apply this excellent example to my needs:

http://code.google.com/p/galleriffic/issues/attachmentText?id=76&aid=-3045121742886940548&name=example-2.html&token=4nlvmgAfVpc5whcXC9UEqHZaSz0%3A1339257750721

With a small twist: both galleries apply the image to the same slideshow container, so instead of having "#thumbs0" thumbnails change the image in "#slideshow0", and "#thumbs1" thumbnails change the image in "#slideshow1" , i have them both set to change the image in "#slideshow" .

This is because I use tabs to separate 2 different categories of thumbnails, that change the image in one single slideshow container.

I did this by setting  imageContainerSel to '#slideshow', instead of '#slideshow'+i like in the example.

Here is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="tabs">
<div class="each-gallery">
    <div id="thumbs0" class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
        </ul>

            <div id="tabs-1">
                <ul class="thumbs noscript">
                    <li>
                        <a class="thumb" href="images/1.jpg" title="Title #0">
                        <img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="Title #0" />
                            Title 1
                        </a>
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div class="image-title">Title 1</div>
                            <div class="image-desc">Description 1</div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="thumb" href="images/2.jpg" title="Title #0">
                            <img src="images/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="Title #0" />
                            Title 2
                        </a>
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div class="image-title">Title 2</div>
                            <div class="image-desc">Description 2</div>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
</div>

            <div id="tabs-2">
                <div class="each-gallery">
                    <div id="thumbs1" class="navigation">

                <ul class="thumbs noscript">
                    <li>
                        <a class="thumb" href="images/3.jpg" title="Title #0">
                        <img src="images/thumbs/3.jpg" alt="Title #0" />
                            Title 3
                        </a>
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div class="image-title">Title 3</div>
                            <div class="image-desc">Description 3</div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="thumb" href="images/4.jpg" title="Title #0">
                            <img src="images/thumbs/4.jpg" alt="Title #0" />
                            Title 4
                        </a>
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div class="image-title">Title 4</div>
                            <div class="image-desc">Description 4</div>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                            // We only want these styles applied when javascript is enabled
                            // We only want these styles applied when javascript is enabled
                            $('div.navigation').css({'width' : '960px', 'float' : 'left'});
                            $('div.content').css('display', 'block');

                            $(".each-gallery").each(function(i){
                                    // Initially set opacity on thumbs and add
                                    // additional styling for hover effect on thumbs
                                    var onMouseOutOpacity = 0.67;
                                    $('#thumbs + i + ul.thumbs li').opacityrollover({
                                            mouseOutOpacity:   onMouseOutOpacity,
                                            mouseOverOpacity:  1.0,
                                            fadeSpeed:         'fast',
                                            exemptionSelector: '.selected'
                                    });

                                    // Initialize Advanced Galleriffic Gallery
                                    var gallery = $('#thumbs'+i).galleriffic({

                                            delay:                     2500,
                                            numThumbs:                 20,
                                            preloadAhead:              0,
                                            enableTopPager:            false,
                                            enableBottomPager:         false,
                                            maxPagesToShow:            7,
                                            imageContainerSel:         '#slideshow',
                                            controlsContainerSel:      '#controls',
                                            captionContainerSel:       '#caption',
                                            loadingContainerSel:       '#loading',
                                            renderSSControls:          true,
                                            renderNavControls:         true,
                                            playLinkText:              'Play Slideshow',
                                            pauseLinkText:             'Pause Slideshow',
                                            prevLinkText:              '&lsaquo; Previous Photo',
                                            nextLinkText:              'Next Photo &rsaquo;',
                                            nextPageLinkText:          'Next &rsaquo;',
                                            prevPageLinkText:          '&lsaquo; Prev',
                                            enableHistory:             false,
                                            autoStart:                 false,
                                            syncTransitions:           true,
                                            defaultTransitionDuration: 900,
                                            onSlideChange:             function(prevIndex, nextIndex) {
                                                    // 'this' refers to the gallery, which is an extension of $('#thumbs')
                                                    this.find('ul.thumbs').children()
                                                            .eq(prevIndex).fadeTo('fast', onMouseOutOpacity).end()
                                                            .eq(nextIndex).fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
                                            },
                                            onPageTransitionOut:       function(callback) {
                                                    this.fadeTo('fast', 0.0, callback);
                                            },
                                            onPageTransitionIn:        function() {
                                                    this.fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
                                            }
                                    });
                            });

                    });
            </script>
```

**The problem:**

on page load, both galleries load their first image to #slideshow at the same time, so on initial page load, the image appears twice, one below the other. Only after clicking on a different thumbnail the second image disappears and everything works as expected.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem myself.

In case anyone is interested, here is the solution:

I gave the first thumb in the first gallery a unique name:

```
<a class="thumb" name="first" href="images/1.jpg" title="Title #0">
```

And modified jquery.galleriffic.js:

```
                var buuga = this.data[nextIndex].hash;
            if(buuga !== 'first') {
                            var newSlide = this.$imageContainer
                .append('<span class="image-wrapper current"><a class="advance-link" rel="history" href="#'+this.data[nextIndex].hash+'" title="'+imageData.title+'">&nbsp;</a></span>')
                .find('span.current').css('opacity', '0');
            }
```

What i changed was adding the 'buuga' variable to store the name, and wrapped the part that constructs a new hidden span for the image in an "if" condition that does not run if the name is "first'.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, doing so only hides the *first* image. I have a variable amount of galleries/folders that will be used, so in the case of 3 galleries, the other 2 images are showing.

Now, when I change it from:

```
var buuga = this.data[nextIndex].hash;
```

To:

```
var buuga = this.data[imageData.index].hash;
```

it works perfectly on page load. Except that the first image is the only image that shows when clicking the thumbnails. What ended up happening was that galleriffic tried to append three images to the first span.

What I ended up doing was adding two globals: a counting number, and a total folder count number.

```
firstImageCount = 0;  
totalFolderCount = 3; // this number is generated with php
```

and what I ended up doing to the jquery.galleriffic.js:

```
// Construct new hidden span for the image
var firstHash = this.data[nextIndex].hash; // I changed buuga to this more descriptive name
if(firstImageCount >= totalFolderCount-1){  
    var newSlide = this.$imageContainer  
       .append('<span class="image-wrapper current"><a class="advance-link" rel="history" href="#'+this.data[nextIndex].hash+'" title="'+imageData.title+'">&nbsp;</a></span>')  
       .find('span.current').css('opacity', '0');  
}  
firstImageCount++;
```

Then I had it show the last folder in the series first, since that is the image that loads.